# Android SQLite INSERT or REPLACE

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am trying the INSERT OR REPLACE syntax in SQLite with no success so far because no rows are inserted.

My Create table query is

```
 create table providers (provider_id text not null, provider_name text not null,  provider_channel_id text not null, channel_name text not null);CREATE UNIQUE INDEX channel_id ON providers (provider_channel_id);
```

My INSERT OR Replace query is

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO providers (provider_channel_id, channel_name, provider_id, provider_name) VALUES ('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you create `provider_id` column but insert into `provider_channel_id` column?

Comment: provider_channel_id is the column on which conflict should be detected, in query columns are quite out of order :)

Answer (score 5):

the solution that i found 
.replace instead of insert 
you should also have a row id in the table and set it as PRIMARY KEY

```
 bdd.replace(table,null, contentValues);
```