# SQLite Insert or Replace works outside Android but not in the code?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an insert or replace command similar to this:

```
INSERT or REPLACE INTO author(id,bookId,name) values((SELECT id FROM author WHERE bookId='4'),'4','Book Title')
```

Basically, it replaces a row if an id exists that aligns with a a bookId. If there is no id it inserts.

I'm using an application called "SQLite Database Browser 2.0" to test my SQLite commands on the same database tables I have in my app (I'm exporting the database from the emulator). The above command works like a charm in the Database Browser but the app doesn't insert or replace (right now it should insert since the table is empty).

I know my SQLite command is correct and I don't get any errors in my Logcat.

Am I missing a piece Android needs to do this command?

Comment: is it inserting the value if bookId not exists .?

Comment: No, it's not inserting. I exported the database from the emulator and literally ran the same SQLite statement the app runs and it works. (I'm logging each statement to the logcat).

Comment: Which code you use to execute this, `execSQL()` or `rawQuery()`? Or perhaps can you post the snippet to insert your data in Android? (Also, look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224964/android-sqlite-insert-or-replace?rq=1))

Comment: if it is not giving error then data must be inserted , are you sure that u have used beginTranstion and committed it .

Comment: @AndrewT. - I'm using rawQuery. Changed it to execSQL and it worked. Can you provide this as the answer so I can select it?

Comment: laalto has answered it, although I'm still not sure the reason. `rawQuery()` still executes the query if it is `SELECT` statement, but based on many experiences, for non-query statement, `execSQL()` can do it instead of `rawQuery()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question comments, the problem is that `rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL you pass in but does not execute it. To execute SQL compiled with `rawQuery()`, you generally would issue one of the `moveTo...()` calls on the returned `Cursor`.

In this case, to both compile and execute the SQL, use `execSQL()`.